# Internal server error after I try to host code on server

Tags: python, google-oauth, redirect, youtube-data-api, google-authentication

I have written a code in python using youtube data API v3 where I am listing playlists created by a user. I have followed the code suggested by youtube API it runs well in local machine but when I deployed the same code on the server, It runs till authentication but after OAuth, it displays `Internal server error` in the browser instead of the result.

is there any major changes that I am missing. Please help me with the issue.

My code in not running after `oauth2callback` function runs.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: I have edited the code and added the authorize and oauthtocallback function.  please see it again.

Comment: Please include the exact error message google is returning to you so that we can besure that this is an internal server error from google and not from your server.

Comment: google is returning: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: My application is live on: pricemonitor.info/YT_search

Comment: python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 262, in parse_authorization_code_response, /site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 203, in parse_request_uri_response, /site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 208, in fetch_token, /site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 241, in fetch_token

Comment: I get the errors  mentioned in abovr comment

Comment: @ArjunBorkhatariya the information you posted in the comment section MUST be added in your question. **Click here for [edit] your question** and add the details. Comments are temporal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error,

I was deploying without a secure connection and that was raising an error. also redirect URL must be 'https' that was another problem.